# C++ thread still alive after kill?

Tags: c++, pthreads

I have an issue: I create a thread to execute a command line and sometimes it takes a lot of time for waiting. So, I want to kill this thread and I implement below code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

void* doSomeThing(void *)
{
    cout<<"Begin execute"<<endl;
    system("svn info http://wrong_link_it's_take_a_lot_of_time_to_execute");
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t myThread;

    int err = pthread_create(&myThread,NULL, &doSomeThing,NULL);
    if(err != 0)
    {
        cout<<"Create thread not success"<<endl;
    }

    sleep(2);

    if(pthread_cancel(myThread) == 0)
    {
        cout<<"Thread was be kill"<<endl;
    }

    sleep(3);

    cout<<"End of program";

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using `pthread_cancel` to kill this thread and the line `cout<<"Thread was be kill"<<endl;` always appear after I execute. It is meant this thread being killed, but I saw the surprise [result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9kqV-rFPYjHRzlyNmx0NHBQdDA/view?usp=sharing) when I ran it on Eclipse (both on Ubuntu and Windows 7)

Anybody can explain to me why this thread still alive after kill and can you give me some method to resolve this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Note that you are not just starting a thread but also starting another process using `system()`. BTW: Use `std::thread`. Further, there are C (or even C++) bindings for Subversion, I'd' prefer those, too, over starting commandline processes.

Comment: It means if I require to kill `system ()`, I should kill the process keep this system function, it that's right?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure what your problem really is, I can see nothing unexpected in the behaviour of your program. Also, that picture you linked doesn't tell me anything. However, if you want to stop the operation started by `system()` you will have to terminate the according process. How to do that depends on the OS though. For me, that's another reason to use the Subversion API directly.

Answer (score 2):

cancelling a thread is not *actually* killing it. it just requests cancellation:

> ```
>    pthread_cancel - send a cancellation request to a thread
> ```

(from man pthread_cancel).

> The  pthread_cancel()  function  sends a cancellation request to the
>   thread thread.  Whether and when the target thread reacts to the
>   cancellation
>          request depends on two attributes that are under the control of that thread: its cancelability state and type.

Comment: I knew it.  I tried to use [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html) for my project but it's not effective.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [*Marcus Müller*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4433386/marcus-m%C3%BCller) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28385268/694576), `pthread_cancel()` not necessarily ends the thread addressed.

Do not use `system()` if you want to kill what had been run.

1. Create your own new child process using `fork()`/`exec*()`.
2. If it's time to end the child let the parent issue a `kill()` on the PID returned by `fork()`ing in 1.

Comment: Unfortunately, it was not working, this command line of SVN still run after I kill child process

Comment: You might like to pose another question for this. @dtquang